# Return from function that uses multiple async calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await, axios

So the basic idea was to write a method that will scrap webpage to get JSON data that contains rating of a product. Then call this method multipletimes over few domains (.de, .uk, .fr, .nl etc) to collect all ratings.

So I ended up with `scrapWebPage` method which scraps single page:

```
const scrapWebPage = async (countryAppData, productNumber) => {
    const shopUrl = `https://www.shopExample.${countryAppData.countryCode}/?q=${productNumber}`
    const avoidCORSUrl = 'https://allorigins.me/get?url=' + shopUrl + '&callback=?'

    return await axios
        .get(avoidCORSUrl, {xmlMode: false, normalizeWhitespace: true})
        .then(response => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
            let scrapedWebPageJson

            contentForParsing = $("script").get().children[0].data                   
            scrapedWebPageJson = JSON.parse(contentForParsing)

            return scrapedWebPageJson
        })
}
```

`scrapWebPage` also contains some parsing to return some JSON data I want - it resolves correctly (tested this) and returns Promise.

But then I'd like to call this method over multiple domains so I created `getProductDataFromManyDomains`:

```
const getProductDataFromManyDomains = (productNum) => {
    let prodData = {
        reviews: []
    }

    const appCountries = [
        {countryCode: 'nl'}, 
        {countryCode: 'pl'},
        {countryCode: 'de'}
    ]

    appCountries.forEach(async countryApp => {
        let countryData = {}

        let parsedWebPage = await scrapWebPage(countryApp, productNum)

        countryData.countryCode  = countryApp.countryCode
        countryData.ratingCount  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingCount
        countryData.ratingValue  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingValue
        countryData.reviews      = parsedWebPage.reviews   

        prodData.reviews.push(countryData)
    })

    return prodData
}
```

And now I receive `prodData` before populating... while I'd like to receive actual data (populated `prodData`).

I'm not sure how I should construct this `getProductDataFromManyDomains` method to actually return data and not `prodData` before populating. Is that possible? Or what is good pattern here to deal with stuff like that?

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `.forEach()`.  The `for` loop will pause for `await`, the `.forEach()` loop will not.  Then, `getProductDataFromManyDomains()` will need to be async and will return a promise with your final result.

Comment: @jfriend00 WAT?! TIL, thanks!

Comment: @jfriend00 Im not quite catching you... I can do `for (let countryApp of appCountries) {...}` and `getProductDataFromManyDomains` async but what exactly should I then return in this method? I guess not `return prodData` since it wouldn't get populated... I'm lost :/

Comment: @stackustack - Code example put into an answer below.

Comment: Using synchronous requests to pull data from different domains is a terrible idea. Such request must be done asynchronously.

Comment: FYI, the English word for what you're doing with these web pages is typically "scrape", not "scrap".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `for` loop instead of `.forEach()`. The `for` loop will pause for await, the `.forEach()` loop will not.  This is because the `async` callback you pass to `.forEach()` will return a promise, but `.forEach()` is not designed to do anything with that promise so it does not wait for it to resolve before continuing the loop, but a `for` loop using `await` does.

Then, `getProductDataFromManyDomains()` will need to be `async` and will return a promise with your final result.

```
async function getProductDataFromManyDomains(productNum) {
    let prodData = {
        reviews: []
    }

    const appCountries = [
        {countryCode: 'nl'}, 
        {countryCode: 'pl'},
        {countryCode: 'de'}
    ]

    for (let countryApp of appCountries) {
        let countryData = {}

        let parsedWebPage = await scrapWebPage(countryApp, productNum)

        countryData.countryCode  = countryApp.countryCode
        countryData.ratingCount  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingCount
        countryData.ratingValue  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingValue
        countryData.reviews      = parsedWebPage.reviews   

        prodData.reviews.push(countryData)
    })

    // this will be the resolved value of the promise that
    //   getProductDataFromManyDomains() returns
    return prodData;
}

// usage
getProductDataFromManyDomains(productNum).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

You could also run your multiple requests in parallel rather than one at a time, but since you originally attempted to make your code do them one at a time, I showed you how to do that.

If you wanted to do them in parallel, you would just accumulate the promises in an array and use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done and you would not `await` the request.

Here's a version of the code that runs the requests in parallel, using `.map()` and `Promise.all()`:

```
function getProductDataFromManyDomains(productNum) {
    let prodData = {
        reviews: []
    }

    const appCountries = [
        {countryCode: 'nl'}, 
        {countryCode: 'pl'},
        {countryCode: 'de'}
    ]

    return Promise.all(appCounteries.map(countryApp => {

        return scrapWebPage(countryApp, productNum).then(parsedWebPage => {
            let countryData = {}
            countryData.countryCode  = countryApp.countryCode
            countryData.ratingCount  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingCount
            countryData.ratingValue  = parsedWebPage.aggregateRating.ratingValue
            countryData.reviews      = parsedWebPage.reviews 
            return countryData;         
        });
    })).then(results => {
        // put results into prodData and make that the resolved value
        prodData.reviews = results;
        return prodData;
    });
}

getProductDataFromManyDomains(productNum).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: HTTP requests that pull data from different domains should absolutely do it asynchronously. Otherwise, you are wasting a lot of time when doing it synchronously.

Comment: @vitaly-t - The OP wrote code to do them one at a time so it appears they wanted to do it that way which is why I showed them how to do it that way.  I've added more info to my answer on how to do them in parallel if they want.

Comment: @vitaly-t - I added a version of the code that runs the requests in parallel.

Comment: @jfriend00 oh! I was not aware if i just make func async it will return promise automatically! This solves my problem :) Regarding making the calls synchronously - yeap, I'm aware its bad idea, but didn't want to go too far with stuff I'm not feeling comfortable with. I'l do it as next step :)

Comment: @stackustack - There's no free lunch with `async/await`.  It doesn't really "block" overall interpreter execution, it just pauses one function and then immediately returns a promise from that function.  That promise will be resolved when that function finally finishes and returns.  All `async` functions return a promise automatically.  It is definitely worth fully understanding that.  So, `await` works within the `async` function to pause execution, but doesn't pause execution outside that function (the outside world gets a promise that tells it when that function is actually done).